# Simulation terminated with exit code: 132

Tags: c++, installation, simulation, omnet++

I am Mac OS 10.11 (El Capitan) user. I used 4.6 and when I tried to build some simulation I always get "Simulation terminated with exit code: 139" and couldn’t do nothing at all with that. I thought that when I install 5.0 then everything will be fine, but now I get something like that:

```
Simulation terminated with exit code: 132
Working directory: /Users/JL_Data/omnetpp-5.0/samples/tictoc
Command line: tictoc -r 0 --debug-on-errors=false omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:
PATH=/Users/JL_Data/omnetpp-5.0/bin::/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/JL_Data/omnetpp-5.0/lib::
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=/Users/JL_Data/omnetpp-5.0/images
```

And when I tried open some simulation in terminal I get:

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Do you have some idea what can I do with that problem? I tried to find something on the internet, but after one day I do not get any idea.

If you need some more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As it is right now, your question is not completely clear, since it requires one to be familiar with omnet++ and probably some experience installing and setting it up. However, let me make a couple guesses.

First, `Illegal instruction`. This usually occurs when the binary was built for an architecture different than the one it's being run on; e.g. when then SSE2 or AVX instructions are present in the binary code, but are missing on the CPU.

See, for example, this SO question:

[Find which assembly instruction caused an Illegal Instruction error without debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354147/find-which-assembly-instruction-caused-an-illegal-instruction-error-without-debug)

There is also a question that discusses exactly your problem, namely, "Illegal instruction: 4" on OS X:

[What is the "Illegal Instruction: 4" error and why does "-mmacosx-version-min=10.x" fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268887/what-is-the-illegal-instruction-4-error-and-why-does-mmacosx-version-min-10)

Now, since omnet++ appears to be an open source project, I expect it to have a mailing list and / or an IRC channel. Indeed, here is the communications page on the official website that links to a Google Groups-based mailing list:

https://omnetpp.org/get-involved

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/omnetpp

I advise you to get in touch with the developers with a thorough description of your problem, since the chances of them knowing the solution are significantly higher compared to the chances of there being a user on SO who has faced similar problems when installing an identical version of omnet++ on an identical version of Mac OS X.