# Illegal instruction - haskell

Tags: haskell

I am building using the regular `cabal build` on my local machine, and the binary works fine. But when I copy the binary to another server for tests (same architecture : x86_64 and same glic and so on, as afar as I can tell) I get illegal instruction when I try to run it.

Is there some flag I should pass to cabal to make it compile a more generic binary maybe ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide full error logs?

Comment: illegal instruction is the full error log, it's not a compile time error

Comment: It looks as if the compiler used some CPU instruction which is available on your first machine but not the other one. If those are linux, you could compare `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and observe that some flags are different, pointing to some missing instruction. Also try `file yourExecutable` to confirm it's really a `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64`. I don't know how to create a more generic binary, however. Maybe you need some llvm flags (if ghc is going through llvm).

Comment: Yes, my local cpu is much more recent than the server's one. I did check with file that the binary is a regular 64 bit executable, it is, I just have no idea how to tell cabal build to use -march=generic -mtune=generic basically, as I would do in C

Comment: You would need to build GHC compiler and library for the target environment. There is a fair amount of information if you search for "cross-compiling Haskell".

Comment: Can you try to locate the illegal instruction? You can use [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40223712/5684257), maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike with GCC, the GHC compiler has only a handful of options to tune instruction sets, and they're *all off by default.*  The complete list is:

```
-msse -msse2 -msse3 -msse4 -msse4.2 -mbmi -mbmi2 -mavx -mavx2
-mavx512cd -mavx512er -mavx512f -mavx512pf
```

but there's no corresponding `-mno-sse` or similar options to turn them off because, like I say, they're off by default.  (Well, actually, on the x86_64 architecture, the `-msse` and `-msse2` flags are technically forced on and can't be disabled.)

So, the problem is probably something else, most likely an incompatible or corrupt library.  It might be helpful to run under `gdb` to get a backtrace and see if you can spot a suspicious library or other obvious cause.